# Android Google Nearby Message API subscribe not work in background mode

Tags: android, google-nearby

I have attempted to run google example code about Google Nearby Message API: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby/tree/master/messages/NearbyBackgroundBeacons

The app only receive message in foreground mode. **Is it possible to make the app work in background mode**? Could you guys give me the advise.

Thank you!